# Why are stale header values still around when uploading a subsequent Item to archive.org using ia-wrapper?

Tags: python, http-headers, wrapper, archive

I mirrored a batch of videos from EuroPython2014 on archive.org using the master of ia-wrapper. As discussed in [#64](https://github.com/jjjake/ia-wrapper/issues/64), metadata from the previous upload shows up in a subsequent upload.

I went through and hand edited the descriptions in the archive.org interface (it was just a few of the videos), but I'd like for this not to happen the next time I mirror a conference. I have a workaround (explicitly set headers when calling upload.) I'd really really really like to know how it is that the headers dict is still populated from previous calls.

When I run this, [item.py L579](https://github.com/jjjake/ia-wrapper/blob/master/internetarchive/item.py#L579) is not passing headers in kwargs when it calls upload_file. (I even stepped through using pycharm's debugger).

What the heck is going on?

If you want to try this out, the code below demonstrates it.

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/jjjake/ia-wrapper.git@9b7b951cfb0e9266f329c9fa5a2c468a92db75f7#egg=internetarchive-master`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
import internetarchive as ia
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('IAS3_ACCESS_KEY') 
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('IAS3_SECRET_KEY')

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S')

item = ia.Item('test_upload_iawrapper_first_%s' % now)
item2 = ia.Item('test_upload_iawrapper_second_%s' % now)

def upload(item, metadata):
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as fh:
        fh.write('testing archive_uploader')
        item.upload(fh.name,
            metadata=metadata,
            access_key=ACCESS_KEY,
            secret_key=SECRET_KEY,
            # adding headers={} is a workaround
        )

upload(item,
       metadata={
           'collection': 'test_collection',
           'description': 'not an empty description',
        })

upload(item2,
       metadata={
           'collection': 'test_collection',
           # you can also comment out description and get hte same result
           'description': '',
        })

print 'visit https://archive.org/details/{}'.format(item.identifier)
print 'visit https://archive.org/details/{}'.format(item2.identifier)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tripped over the "mutable defaults" gotcha in Python: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Change this:

```
def upload_file(self, body, headers={}, ...):
```

to this:

```
def upload_file(self, body, headers=None, ...):
    if headers is None:
        headers = {}
```